# how to add myApp to complete action using?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, intentfilter

when you click on a video android give you some suggestion app to open the video i wnat to add my app to the list. name of the list is complete action using and this doc is related https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html
but i am beginner and dont know how to use the doc for video

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and please guide me how to handle the intent in activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code into your manifest in your activity tag :

```
    <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    </intent-filter>
```

It will show your app into a suggestion list whenever user selects a video file from his phone. ALthough, you need to handle the further actions  in your videoplayer activity.

Because this tag will only help you getting your into a suggestion list, to play a selected video, you have to use intent to get the selected video uri. You can find the examples of playing a video file like this on the internet easily.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I know to achieve this kind of things.

[**BroadcastReceiver**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver)

- ***Manifest.xml***

```xml
<application
...
    <!-- BROADCAST RECEIVER -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.package.app.Broadcaster"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
    ...
    </activity>
...
</application>
```

- ***com.package.app.Broadcaster***

```java
public final class Broadcaster extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public final void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        //Activity to handle the files.
        intent.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
        //RuntimeException without this flag.
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

[**Service**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service)

- ***Manifest.xml***

```xml
<application
...
    <!-- SERVICE -->
    <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name="com.package.app.Servicer"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
                <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
    ...
    </activity>
...
</application>
```

- ***com.package.app.Servicer***

```java
public final class Servicer extends Service
{
    @Override
    public final int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
        //Activity to handle the files
        intent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
        //RuntimeException without this flag.
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        //Stop this service.
        stopSelfResult(startId);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public final IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```